# Versions of Package with YUM

Tags: linux, yum

I want to know which versions of the same package were previously installed with YUM. For example if I have a package that it version is 4.0, I should need to know the previously versions installed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at yum history?

That's what I use to find out what have been updated on Red Hat box.

[Here is an article on redhat.com homepage.](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Yum-Transaction_History.html)

For example:

```
yum history package-list foo\*
```

Comment: Yes I tried it. But doesn't show the previous versions ,,,

Comment: If the package was installed previously by yum then AFAIK it *should* show the version...

Comment: Parse your YUM logs for the relevant history.

Comment: Seriously though, `yum history package-list` does just what Jorge is asking for;
     `to trace the history of subscription-manager and related packages, type the following at a shell prompt: "yum history package-list subscription-manager\*"` see link I posted in answer: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Yum-Transaction_History.html